# how to delete duplicate sublists from a list on Netlogo

Tags: list, duplicates, netlogo, sublist

I have been working on a model and it requires me to take certain values (3 values) from agent groups and add them to a list with each group being a sublist within the list.

The problem with the code I have written is that it duplicates the sublists, in other words, it creates more of the same sublist!

If anyone can pinpoint whats causing my sublists to duplicate or tell me how to delete the duplicated sublists, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you! :-))

The code I have written is as follows:

```
to find-dpc
  let a 1
  ;repeat team_members [
  repeat team-number [
  ask teammembers with [label = a] [
  let v-dpc  [dpc] of teammembers with [label = a]
  let v-dpis [dpis] of teammembers with [label = a]
  let v-dppd [dppd] of teammembers with [label = a]
  set var-list-dpc lput v-dpc var-list-dpc 
  set var-list-dpis lput v-dpis var-list-dpis
  set var-list-dppd lput v-dppd var-list-dppd
  ]
  set a a + 1
     remove_duplicates
  ]
end
```

Comment: The `repeat` command does exactly what it says: repeats.  It is a basic deterministic loop, where the first argument is the number of repetitions.